# AlarmManager doesnot work from bootservice receiver

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-bootstrap

I have made an application that requires alarms to be fired.Alarm Manager works fine when they are scheduled from some activity. Since alarms are deleted when  reboot occurs,i have made a boot_Receiver to reschedule the alarms. But the problem is that alarms are not fired when they are scheduled from the bootreceiver class. Please Help..

AlarmManager Class:-

```
public class NotifyService extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Notification_Holder notifholder;
    Type t=new TypeToken<Notification_Holder>(){}.getType();

    Gson js=new Gson();
    notifholder=js.fromJson(intent.getStringExtra("one"),t);
    Notification_Creator notifcreator=new                    Notification_Creator(notifholder.title,notifholder.content,notifholder.cal,context);
    notifcreator.create_notification();
}
}
```

BootReceiver class:-

```
public class AtBoot extends BroadcastReceiver {
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
AlarmManager alarmManager;
Intent x;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("todoshared", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String f = sharedPreferences.getString("todolist", null);
    Gson json = new Gson();
    alarmManager=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        vClass.notes = Notification_Holder.convert_from_jason(f);
    x=new Intent(context,NotifyService.class);
    pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getService(context,2100,x,0);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),pendingIntent);
    Vibrator vib=(Vibrator)context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    if(vib.hasVibrator()) {
        vib.vibrate(1500);
    }
```

}
}

Manifest File:-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />





<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/MyAppBar">


    <activity
        android:name=".scrapper"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".schedule"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".workSpace"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <receiver android:name=".widget">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".widgetService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" />

    <receiver android:name=".NotifyService" />



    <activity
        android:name=".showSubject"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.popupTheme" />

    <activity android:name=".splashScreen"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".AtBoot"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="AtBoot">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

I have added the vibrator in AtBoot class t check if it is being called on bootup. And the phone vibrates..This means that the class is being invoked on bootup but the alarm part does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for HTC you should also add in the IntentFilters
 `<action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>`

Also, I think it should be
`PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 2100, x, 0);`
and not
`PendingIntent.getService(context,2100,x,0);`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i was using pendingintent.getService() instead of pendingIntent.getBroadcast() as correctly pointed out by Velislava...